# H2 Database duplicates removal

Tags: h2

I wish to operate on duplicate rows in a H2 database table (DELETE would be a chance, SETting new value another).

Let's prepare some sample data:

```
create table receipt( id int primary key, receipt_number varchar(52), shop_id int);
insert into receipt(id, receipt_number, shop_id) values(1,'A',1);
insert into receipt(id, receipt_number, shop_id) values(2,'A',1);
insert into receipt(id, receipt_number, shop_id) values(3,'B',1);
insert into receipt(id, receipt_number, shop_id) values(4,'A',2);
select * from receipt;
select receipt_number, shop_id, count(*) count from receipt group by (receipt_number, shop_id);
```

which leads us to:

[image: sql output]

I thought that this statement would be enough:

```
merge into receipt as t1
using ( select receipt_number, shop_id, count(*) count from receipt group by (receipt_number, shop_id) ) as t2 on t1.receipt_number = t2.receipt_number
when matched and count > 1 then delete;
```

but an exception is raised:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "MERGE INTO RECEIPT AS T1 
    USING ( SELECT RECEIPT_NUMBER, SHOP_ID, COUNT(*) COUNT FROM RECEIPT GROUP BY (RECEIPT_NUMBER, SHOP_ID) ) AS T2 ON T1[*].RECEIPT_NUMBER = T2.RECEIPT_NUMBER 
    WHEN MATCHED AND COUNT > 1 THEN DELETE "; expected "("; SQL statement:
merge into receipt as t1 
    using ( select receipt_number, shop_id, count(*) count from receipt group by (receipt_number, shop_id) ) as t2 on t1.receipt_number = t2.receipt_number 
    when matched and count > 1 then delete [42001-197] 42001/42001
```

You can easily test my code running

```
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -p 8082:81  oscarfonts/h2
```

the browse to `http://localhost:8082/` login and copy&paste code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it with

```
delete receipt 
where id > (select min(id) from receipt t2 where receipt.receipt_number = t2.receipt_number and receipt.shop_id = t2.shop_id )
```

guess I can also use it for `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: The answer from Irkwz deletes all entries except the one with the lowest id (at least this happened in my trials.

Here is a better solution (tested on H2), but still not perfect as it removes only one duplicate per constraint per execution:

```
delete from receipt 
where id in (
    select max(t2.id) 
    from receipt t2 
    group by t2.receipt_number, t2.shop_id 
    having count(t2.id) > 1
);
```